# Unable to see Node option in Jenkins 'Global Configure' after installing the plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I've installed the NodeJS plugin as suggested in the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

[image]

But it fail to work, when I run `npm install` through `Execute Shell`; so, I suggested to config the nodejs in the `global config` but it fail to display the node layout in the page as given below

http://localhost:8080/configureTools/

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [nodejs.hpi](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/nodejs.hpi) and upload it from http://localhost:8080/pluginManager/advanced

[image]

Now navigate to http://localhost:8080/configureTools/

[image]